# Infeasible results in bisection algorithm for Quasi-Convex/Concave Feasibility Question

Tags: convex-optimization, taylor-expansion

I am studying [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8799031) and trying to repeat the programme. The codes I wrote based on the paper works well however there's a situation which makes me confuse. Sometimes the feasible will never be solved.
[image]
The bisection programme in this paper is based on [Foundations of User-Centric Cell-Free Massive MIMO](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9336188) Section 3.4.1, P95. The algorithm previously set a maximum value and a lowest value (from some [github codes](https://github.com/hienquocngo/Cell-Free-Massive-MIMO-Versus-Small-Cells/blob/master/DL_PowerAllocation_MaxMin_correlation.m), for example they would be "tmin=2^Y-1" and "tmax=2^(2*Y+1.2)-1", Y is a pre-measured value), and then convert the question into a feasible question. The values of tmin and tmax change based on the feasible results until their difference reach a threshold, and the $log_2((\frac{{tmin}+{tmax}}{2})+1)$ is the result y of the optimization value.

Since there's $x^2$ in the objective function in the paper, the First-order Taylor exapansion is used. The basic bisection method becomes [image]
A defult $x_k$ is set, using the bisection algorithm to find the next $x_{k+1}$ until it reaches the optimal point. The result y at the optimal x* is the solution of the optimization problem.

Then back to my question. Because of at some points only "infeasible" results are given, it means that the optimal t* is not contained in the range between (tmin, tmax). Within no optimal t* and x* for the former optimization problem, the programme will repeat the previous no-result loop.

So my question is, for bisection problem, is there any method which can find a good range of (tmin,tmax) that can caontain the optimal t* ? Or, if there're only "infeasible" results, can I still use some method that find the optimal t* and x* for the next iteration $x_{k+1}$? Thank you.